# Integrate $\sqrt{x^2 - 2x}$

Tags: integration

$$\int{\sqrt{x^2 - 2x}}$$

I think I should be doing trig substitution, but which? I completed the square giving

$$\int{\sqrt{(x-1)^2 -1}}$$

But the closest I found is  for

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 - (x+b)^2}}$$

So I must add a $-$, but how?

Comment: $x-1=\sec\theta$, then use $\sec^2\theta-1=\tan^2\theta$ to simplify.

Comment: @DavidMitra, just curious if theres some other way of solving this problem? I don't remember that as an identity taught/in my formula sheet. Of course theres lots of identities not taught, but usually, questions (at least for school) are of similar difficulty

Comment: @DavidMitra, I mean how did you get $x-1 = \sec{\theta}$

Comment: @Jiew Meng I just decided to make that substitution. Then I could use the identity $\sec^2\theta-1=\tan^2\theta$ to get rid of the square root.

Comment: Since it is a difference of squares, you should draw a right triangle, then put lengths on the edges suggested by that difference of squares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to solve these problems is indeed with trigonometric substitutions. 
But it is not the *only* way to solve these. 
Another way that was used more before is called *Euler substitutions*

> if we are to integrate $\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}$ that has real roots $\alpha$ and
>   $\beta$, then we can use the substitution $\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}=x \cdot t$

Now, in your problem we have $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=2$, so we may choose to use the substitution

$$ \sqrt{x^2-2x} = (x-0)\cdot t \ \Rightarrow \ x = \frac{2}{1-t^2}$$

Since this is homework and I am lazy, so from here I will only outline the details

$$ \begin{align} I & = \int \sqrt{x^2-2x}\,\mathrm{d}x \\
                   & = \int \frac{8t^2}{1-3t^2+3t^4-t^6}\,\mathrm{d}t \\
                   & = \int -\frac{8t^2}{(t+1)^3(t-1)^3}\,\mathrm{d}t \\
                   & = \int - \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{t+1} + \frac{1}{(t+1)^3} 
- \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(t+1)^2} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(t-1)^2} - \frac{1}{(t-1)^3} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(t-1)^2} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
\end{align} $$

and from here the rest is obvious =)

Comment: @KannappanSampath Not really. What Nebu is introducing is a type of Euler substitution, which is great for this kind of problems. It is then simply a matter of rolling back to the original variable not get the result.

Comment: @KannappanSampath I see.

Answer (score 2):

In hopes of taking advantage of the identity
$$\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta-1,$$ make the substitution:
 $$x-1=\sec\theta, \quad dx=\sec\theta\,\tan\theta\,d\theta.$$ 
Then we have
$$
\int \sqrt{(x-1)^2-1}\, dx = \int\sqrt{\sec^2\theta -1}\, \sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta
=\int\tan^2\theta\sec\theta\,d\theta=\int (\sec^3\theta-\sec\theta)\,d\theta.
$$

To integrate $\sec\theta$, you can use a trick:
$$\tag{1}
\int\sec\theta\,d\theta
=\int\sec\theta \cdot {\textstyle{\sec\theta+\tan\theta\over\sec\theta+\tan\theta}}\,d\theta
=\int{ {\textstyle{\sec^2\theta+\sec\theta\tan\theta\over \sec\theta+\tan\theta}}}d\theta=\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|+C\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
$$

To integrate $\sec^3\theta$, you can start with integration by parts:
$$\eqalign{
\color{maroon}{\int\sec^3\theta\,d\theta}=\int\underbrace{\sec \theta}_u \,\underbrace{\sec^2\theta d\theta}_{dv}
&= \underbrace{\sec \theta}_u \,\underbrace{\tan\theta}_{v} -
\int\underbrace{\tan \theta}_v\, \underbrace{\sec \theta\tan\theta\, d\theta}_{du}\cr
&=\sec\theta\tan\theta -\int( \sec^3\theta-\sec\theta)\,d\theta\cr
&=\sec\theta\tan\theta \color{maroon}{-\int \sec^3\theta\,d\theta}+\int \sec\theta\,d\theta.
}
$$
Then, in the above,  solve for $\color{maroon}{\int\sec^3\theta\,d\theta}$:
$$\tag{2}
\int\sec^3\theta\,d\theta={1\over2}\sec\theta\tan\theta+{1\over2}\int\sec\theta\,d\theta
={1\over2}\sec\theta\tan\theta+{1\over2}\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|+C.
$$

So, using $(1)$ and $(2)$:
$$
\int(\sec^3\theta-\sec\theta)\,d\theta 
={1\over2}\sec\theta\tan\theta -{1\over2}\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|+C.
$$
Finally put everything back in terms of $x$ using $\theta=\sec^{-1}(x-1)$ (which I'll leave to you).

Comment: Oh, I did it wrong $\int{\sqrt{\sec^2{\theta}-1}}$ without the $\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta$ part. But how did you get that?

Comment: @JiewMeng $dx=\sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta$.

Comment: @Jiew Meng: We want to somehow get rid of the square root. The identity $\sec^2 u -1=\tan^2 u$ is one way. Another approach is to use the hyperbolic function identity $\cosh^2 u -\sinh^2 u=1$. There are others.

Answer (score 1):

The main obstacle here is the square root.  It is likely that eliminating it will allow us to proceed.  So we want something squared minus 1 is the square of something.  That leaves secant (or cosecant) as the best option.

As N3buchadnezzar states, it is not the only option.  Consider the formulas

$(m+n)^2=m^2+2mn+n^2,(m-n)^2=m^2-2mn+n^2$

It is possible to do a substitution such that

$(m+n)^2-1=(m-n)^2$

$(m+n)^2-(m-n)^2=1$

$4mn=1$

So any substitution $x-1=\frac{f(t)}2+\frac1{2f(t)}$ will work, though back substitution may be messy and will likely require the same properties to undo.  For example, let's do

$x-1=\frac12(e^t+e^{-t}),dx=\frac12(e^t-e^{-t})dt$

$\int\sqrt{(x-1)^2-1}dx=\int\frac12(e^t-e^{-t})\sqrt{\frac14(e^{2t}+e^{-2t}+2)-1}dt$=

$\int\frac12(e^t-e^{-t})\sqrt{\frac14(e^{2t}+e^{-2t}+2-4)}dt=$

$\int\frac12(e^t-e^{-t})\sqrt{\frac14(e^{2t}+e^{-2t}-2)}dt=\int(\sqrt{\frac14(e^{2t}+e^{-2t}-2)})^2dt=$

$\frac14\int e^{2t}+e^{-2t}-2dt=\frac18e^{2t}-\frac18e^{-2t}-\frac t2+C$

Now the problem of back-substitution.  How do we get back a function in terms of x?  Well, we have

$x-1=\frac12(e^t+e^{-t}),\sqrt{(x-1)^2-1}=\frac12(e^t-e^{-t})$

$x-1+\sqrt{x^2-2x}=e^t,t=\ln(x-1+\sqrt{x^2-2x})$

That you'll need for the $\frac t2$ term.  For the rest, you'd want to use

$\frac18e^{2t}-\frac18e^{-2t}=\frac12(\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}2)(\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}2)=\frac12(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-2x}$

So, like I said, secant is the best option. :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know i am right or wrong but i can do this example without using trigonometric substitution in following way,
\begin{align*}
\int\sqrt{x^{2}-2x}dx &=\int\sqrt{x^{2}-2x+1-1}dx\
                    &=\int\sqrt{(x-1)^{2}-1^{2}}dx\
                    &=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{(x-1)^{2}-1}-\frac{1}{2}\log |x+\sqrt{(x-1)^{2}-1}|+c.
\end{align*}
I used the following formula of integration,
$\int\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}dx=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}-\frac{a^{2}}{2}\log |x+\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}|+c.$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $y= \sqrt{x^2-2x}$. Then $dy=\frac{x-1}ydx$
\begin{align}\int\sqrt{x^2 - 2x}\ dx
=&\ \frac12\int \frac{y^2+(x-1)^2}y-\frac1y\ dx\\
=&\  \frac12 \int y+\frac{(x-1)^2}y\ dx
-\  \frac12 \int\frac{y+(x-1)}{y(y+x-1)}dx\\
=& \ \frac12\int [ydx+(x-1)dy]- \frac12\int \frac{dx+dy}{y+x-1}\\
=&\ \frac12\int d[(x-1)y]- \frac12 \int \frac{d(y+x-1)}{y+x-1}\\
= &\ \frac12{(x-1)y}-\frac12\ln|y+x-1|
\end{align}